# DMA and Cache using at the same time

Tags: c, linux, caching, linux-kernel, cpu-architecture

What happens  when we use DMA and cache at the same time? What are the cautions that a programmer needs to be taken while using DMA and cache ?

Comment: Use a function like `dma_alloc_coherent()` which is documented in [DMA-API-HOWTO.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt).  Note that most of time you can allocate the memory to be used for DMA as non-cacheable.  Other memory (program data) can be cached.  You may cache only a portion of memory; it is not all or none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DMA will read and write to memory, not cache. For example the DMA controller can update some memory that is currently cached and the change will not be reflected in the data cache. Or you may have modified in the cache data corresponding to an area the DMA ls accessing.
You must tell the cache controller about that. It is very architecture dependant
For example this is controlled using registers of the CP15 coprocessor on ARM architectures (see http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0464f/CIHDGCBH.html)

Comment: x86 caches are DMA coherent, which makes it easy to overlook errors when a driver is developed there.